# How to reload gem for every request in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How is it possible to force reloading a gem for every request?

I develop a gem and would like to reload my gem's code every time when I refresh the page in a browser. My Gemfile:

```
gem "my_gem", :path => "../my_gem"
```

To solve the problem I tried every suggestion listed in stakoverflow. Nothing helped. Also have found two Rails config parameters: watchable_dirs and watchable_files. Tried to use them but they also don't work for me.

Comment: Someone's got to ask: *Why?* What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Jordan question is obvious: because he is developing a gem, he wants to change and debug it seamlessly.

Comment: I guess, you should require your gem with a `to_prepare` statement in it's initializer file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events

Comment: @apneadiving I've tried two options in development.rb:

(1)
`MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.to_prepare do
    require "../my_gem/lib/my_gem/helper.rb"
  end
end`

(2)
`ActionDispatch::Callbacks.to_prepare do
  require "../my_gem/lib/my_gem/helper.rb"
end`

Nothing helps. What is wrong?

Comment: @apneadiving If you look at the revision history you'll see that it was not initially obvious, although that was certainly my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mark the classes you want to reload as unloadable using ActiveSupport::Dependencies unloadable method;

```
class YourClass
  unloadable
end
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Dependencies/Loadable/unloadable and 
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159805560/tips-for-writing-your-own-rails-engine

should give you some background. Alternatively you can do your own reloading like this;

```
Object.send(:remove_const, 'YOUR_CLASS') if Object.const_defined?('YOUR_CLASS')
GC.start
load 'path/to/your_file.rb'
```

Comment: the problem is that I build a module and then include it into ActionView: `ActionView::Base.send :include, MyGem::Helper`. So I don't have classes. In this case where I should use method 'unloadable'?

Comment: Perfect, this solved the problem for me! I just put `unloadable if Rails.env.development?` into my module, and it works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I’ve done quote a bit of hunting around for this, but in the end it took some trial and error.

lib/my_gem/my_gem.rb:

```
require 'active_support/dependencies'
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths += [File.expand_path("..", __FILE__)]

module MyGem
  include ActiveSupport::Dependencies
  unloadable
end
```

Be sure to add “unloadable” to all of your classes as well.